# Bootstrap 5: Variable overwrite doesn't work

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, dart-sass

I try to overwrite some default variables with my own values.

To do this, I'm using the demo code from the Bootstrap docs:

```
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// Default variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;
$table-cell-vertical-align: middle;

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/root";

// 4. Include any optional Bootstrap CSS as needed
@import "../bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// 5. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utililies.scss`
@import "../bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 6. Add additional custom code here
```

The overwrite works for the `$body-bg` and `$body-color`.
But the change in `$table-cell-vertical-align` has no effect.

I also saw an [answer which points out the importance of the order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63679821/1788961).
But as I see it, the order in my file is correct.

And even if I put `$table-cell-vertical-align` at the end of the file it doesn't work.

Do I miss something?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're importing the "../bootstrap/scss/tables" file.

Comment: I saw that just now... :-) Thank you! If you put that as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're importing the `../bootstrap/scss/tables` file.